# Como validar editexts vacios en un recycler view

Tags: android, recyclerview, edittext

soy nuevo en el desarrollo android, estoy intentando validar los editext que tengo en un recycler view para que cuando le den clic al boton "Aceptar", muestre un mensaje de "La cantidad no puede estar vacia" de acuerdo a la posicion en la que se agrego el texto

Este el evento del boton que debe hacer la validacion

```
class PartesAfectadasDialog : DialogFragment(), AgregarCantidad {

btnAceptar.setOnClickListener {
        val fields = arrayOf<EditText>(chooseQttyPart)
        if (validarCamposVacios(fields)) {
            ToastUtils.toastLongError("Debes seleccionar una parte dañada e ingresar su cantidad")
        } else {
            this.addCantidad(qtyGlobal)
            dismiss()
        }
        btnAddAutopistaParts!!.isEnabled = true
        callBackItemCheck!!.listChecks(partesAfectadasAdapter.getItemsChecked())
        listInjured.clear()
        listInjured.addAll(partesAfectadasAdapter.getItemsChecked())
        dismiss()
    }
```

> Este es el metodo que tengo actualmente para validar los editexts

```
fun validarCamposVacios(campos: Array<EditText>): Boolean {
    for (i in campos.indices) {
        val cadena = campos[i].getText().toString()
        if (cadena.trim { it <= ' ' }.isEmpty()) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

> Este es mi model

```
public class ParteAfectadaAutopista extends RealmObject implements Serializable, Keyable, Parcelable {

private Long id;
private String nombre;
private String unidad;
private double costo;
private String cantidadTyped;

public ParteAfectadaAutopista() { }

public ParteAfectadaAutopista(Long id, String nombre, String unidad, float costo, String cantidadTyped) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.unidad = unidad;
    this.costo = costo;
    this.cantidadTyped = cantidadTyped;
}
```

//getter && setter..

> En mi adapter, tengo esta implementacion

Lo que hace aqui esta interface "implQtty!!.addCantidad(part)" agrega lo que se escribe del editext en una lista, en otra clase

```
 class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

fun bindAllCheckeBox(part: ParteAfectadaAutopista, checked: Boolean, listener: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) {
        itemView.checkBoxInjuredParts.text = part.getNombre()
        itemView.checkBoxInjuredParts.isChecked = checked
        itemView.checkBoxInjuredParts.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)

        itemView.chooseQttyPart.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                part.cantidadTyped = itemView.chooseQttyPart.getText().toString()
                implQtty!!.addCantidad(part)
                Log.i("asd", "onTextChanged: ${itemView.chooseQttyPart.getText()}")
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
        })


    }
```

> Dentro de esta clase se encuentra implementada la interface de arriba, y lo que hace es agregar en una lista lo que se typea del editext

```
class PartesAfectadasDialog : DialogFragment(), AgregarCantidad {

override fun addCantidad(qtyy: ParteAfectadaAutopista?) {
    qtyGlobal = qtyy
    if (qtyy != null) {
        val index = getParteId(qtyy.getId())
        if (index >= 0) {
            cantidadSelected[index].setCantidadTyped(qtyy.getCantidadTyped())
        } else {
            cantidadSelected.add(qtyy)
        }
        Log.i("sizelist", "addCantidad: ${cantidadSelected.size}")
    }
}
```

> El resultado de lo que necesito es algo como esto

[image: Necesito que si el checbox esta seleccionado, pero la cantidad esta vacia, que me salte error de acuerdo a la posicion que estoy escribiendo en mi recyclerView]

Answer (score 1):

En tu código, en vez de pasar el contenido del editText a String y hacer un trim, cámbialo en el if por:

```
campos[i].getText().isEmpty()
```